# How to get value from a property in Qml from another Qml?

Tags: qt, qml

I know this question was asked so many times but none of the answeres could help me. I have two QML files. The first Qml file has a map in it and when I press on the map it opens a window with the following Code:

```
MouseArea{
    id: mouseArea
    property var positionRoot: map.toCoordinate(Qt.point(mouseX, mouseY))
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: {
            var component = Qt.createComponent("addAttribute.qml")
            if (component.status === Component.Ready) {
            var dialog = component.createObject(parent,{popupType: 1})
            dialog.show()
       }
    }
}
```

The window has a `label`, `textfield`and a `button`. What I want is to get the value of the `property`(positionRoot) I created in the first QML file. How could I possibly do it?

Comment: Create property of the same type as `positionRoot` in the second window and pass the value while creating - `dialog.positionRoot2 = positionRoot;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @folibis it worked. Here is the Code that needed to be added.

```
MouseArea{
        id: mouseArea
        property var positionRoot: map.toCoordinate(Qt.point(mouseX, mouseY))
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
                var component = Qt.createComponent("addAttribute.qml")
                if (component.status === Component.Ready) {
                var dialog = component.createObject(parent,{popupType: 1})
                dialog.sqlPosition = positionRoot
                dialog.show()
           }
        }
    }
```

And in my second window I just make a new Property called sqlPosition. For example:

```
Window {
        id: secondWindow
        property var sqlPosition
    }
```